# Concat dataframe columns by passing list

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

```
    from pyspark.sql import Row, functions as F
    row = Row("UK_1","UK_2","Date","Cat")
    df = (sc.parallelize
    ([
        row(1,1,'12/10/2016',"A"),
        row(1,2,None,'A'),
        row(2,1,'14/10/2016','B'),
        row(3,3,'!~2016/2/276','B'),
        row(None,1,'26/09/2016','A'),
        row(1,1,'12/10/2016',"A"),
        row(1,2,None,'A'),
        row(2,1,'14/10/2016','B'),
        row(None,None,'!~2016/2/276','B'),
        row(None,1,'26/09/2016','A')
        ]).toDF())

       pks = ["UK_1","UK_2"]

      df1 = (
      df
      .select(columns) 
       #.withColumn('pk',F.concat(pks))
      .withColumn('pk',F.concat("UK_1","UK_2"))
      )

   df1.show()
```

Is there a way I can pass in a list of columns into the concat? I want to use the code for scenarios where the columns can be varying and i would like to pass it as a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is `*args` (variable number of arguments) in python:

```
df.withColumn("pk", F.concat(*pks)).show()

+----+----+------------+---+----+
|UK_1|UK_2|        Date|Cat|  pk|
+----+----+------------+---+----+
|   1|   1|  12/10/2016|  A|  11|
|   1|   2|        null|  A|  12|
|   2|   1|  14/10/2016|  B|  21|  
|   3|   3|!~2016/2/276|  B|  33|
|null|   1|  26/09/2016|  A|null|
|   1|   1|  12/10/2016|  A|  11|
|   1|   2|        null|  A|  12|
|   2|   1|  14/10/2016|  B|  21|
|null|null|!~2016/2/276|  B|null|
|null|   1|  26/09/2016|  A|null|
+----+----+------------+---+----+
```

Comment: I am getting the following error ,AnalysisException: u'cannot resolve \'"UK_1"\' given input columns: [UK_1, UK_2, Date, Cat];'

Comment: It seems you have some extra quotes around column names. You can check `pks`, and make sure the strings don't have unnecessary quotes.